# rosws trouble creating sandbox

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just read this same question and the answer did not help.

I ran rosws init and created the groovy_workspace, then a mkdir to create sandbox and next I did the following:
bill@RobotDev:~$ source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
bill@RobotDev:~$ rosws set ~/groovy__workspace/sandbox
ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.

What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56354/rosws-trouble-creating-sandbox/) by [geriatric_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/4301/geriatric_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is that after the making the directory groovy_workspace, you have to bill@RobotDev:~$ source ~/groovy_workspace/setup.bash
bill@RobotDev:~$ rosws set ~/groovy_workspace/sandbox

```
 Add new elements:
```

sandbox

Continue: (y)es, (n)o: y
Overwriting /home/bill/groovy_workspace/.rosinstall

Do not forget to do ...
$ source /home/bill/groovy_workspace/setup.sh
... in every open terminal.

---

Originally posted by [geriatric_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/4301/geriatric_robot/) with karma: 16 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0